# not understanding parameters of a prior for bayesian linear regression

Tags: regression, bayesian

I am trying to understand the parameters of a prior for doing bayesian linear regression.

$$
\beta|\sigma^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 10^2\sigma^2I) \\
\sigma^2 \sim Inv-\chi^2(1, 5^2)
$$

Let's say I have the above prior, but is based on belief not on any previous data.

I understand that the first parameter 0, means that my belief for all the $\beta$ is 0.

On the inverse chi squared, the 1, can be seen as "fake data points" I see it as "my belief comes from a dataset with only one row". (So, not really strong prior).

Then the $5^2$, would be my best guess for variance of my "fake data".

Overall I see the prior as believing that the betas are 0, not so sure about it (hence the "1"), not only that my prior is really spread(hence the $5^2$)

Now, I do not understand what information $10^2\sigma^2I$ brings to the table?

Comment: Could you give us source for this formula and some broader context?

Comment: Well, it is not for any specific case, I just wanted to make sense out of the parameters for a prior.

Comment: But those parameters without context are meaningless. There's no such a this as "a prior" for regression parameters, there's infinite number of possible priors, depending on context. There's nothing magical about $10^2$, so without context it's hard to say why they used it.

Comment: "I understand that the first parameter 0, means that my belief for all the $\beta$ is 0." -- No. It means that $\beta$ is centered around a normal distribution with mean zero, so that with high probability ($\approx$ 0.95), each element of $\beta$ lies within $\pm 2 \times 10 \times \sigma$. Conditional on a moderately large $\sigma$, this interval can be moderately large. As such, $\beta$ can take a wide range of values. This what we usually mean by saying that we have little information on $\beta$ -- $\beta$ can take a wide range of values with high probability.